# Push Notifications for iPhone - accepted methodolgy

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I’m looking at the designing and developing a service for Push notifications, and am trying to understand the order of processing in the Apple App when it comes to Registering for Push Notifications and storage of the Token.
What I’m developing currently is a service that allows subscription to individual changes that happen to particular processing on our server.
When they happen, the phone user may receive a message of type “A”, “B”, or “C”.
The phone user has to “subscribe” to each of these types individually if they want them. Otherwise they can ignore it and not subscribe.

So User Fred, on Phone #4, starts our App, logs in, and then has the ability to turn on or off subscriptions to events that are sent as Push Notifications.

So I need to tie details from Fred’s login, to Phone #4’s device Token, with particular subscriptions.

So my particularly important questions are.

When the Phone connects to the APNS server to get its device token, is this automatic on app start? Or can this be initiated at a later step?  Ie, after going through a loging screen on our app.

Can we (are we allowed to) store the device token on the phone in the App's data store?. Or, should the App be connecting to the APNS server every time the app is run?

How does the App know if it as already called the APNS server and retrieved a token, or as above, should it call the APNS server time the app is run?

Can we (are we allowed to) store the token in the App’s memory as it runs, so we can properly subscribe and unsubscribe for particular messages?

We need also to be able to list all the subscriptions that a particular user may have across all their devices so the user can remove old devices (if they change phones).  Or can we rely upon data back from calls to the APNS – when we attempt to push a notification - to inform us that a device token is no longer valid?

Or is there some better way of tying this all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When the Phone connects to the APNS server to get its device token, is
>   this automatic on app start? Or can this be initiated at a later step?
>   Ie, after logging into our app.

After the app has started, the app gets the token by calling registerForRemoteNotificationTypes.  This will prompt the user for permission, and call a callback with the device token if permission is granted.

> Can we (are we allowed to) store the device token on the phone in the
>   Apps data store?. Or, should the App be connecting to the APNS server
>   every time the app is run?

You'll need to build an [APN provider](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html), which is a web server that calls apple to send the pushes.  The thing to do with the token is post it to your server that uses the APN provider.  The app doesn't connect to APNS, your provider does, and it does it when it has pushes to send.

> Can we (are we allowed to) store the token in the App’s memory as it
>   runs, so we can properly subscribe and unsubscribe for particular
>   messages?

You can keep the token on the client, but you don't really need to.  It's your web service that calls APN, so it needs to be kept aware of your users' subscription prefs.

> We need also to be able to list all the subscriptions that a
>   particular user may have across all their devices so the user can
>   remove old devices (if they change phones). Or can we rely upon data
>   back from calls to the APNS – when we attempt to push a notification -
>   to inform us that a device token is no longer valid?

APN also provides a feedback service that you call in batch which returns the device tokens that are no longer valid.  Not only *can* you use this service, but you *must*.  Apple will get mad at apps that repeatedly send to no longer valid devices.

> Or is there some better way of tying this all together?

Yes!  [Parse.com](http://www.parse.com) provides a nice wrapper on the client code, does the provider and feedback service, abstracts the idea of single devices to the idea of a "channel" which sounds like just what you need for multiple notification types A, B, C, provides a super-easy step by step setup, and loads of other useful cloud services for iOS.  (I'm not affiliated, but a big fan).

Comment: "After the app has started" is kinda broad. Can you answer if this can be delayed, until further into the app, like on the third page screen?

Comment: Thanks, I'm well aware of we need to build an APN provider. I thought I covered this in describing that we're building a service.  Do we store the token on the Phone, in the App's data store, or can we call the APNS server ever time to retrieve the token?  How does the App know if has already done this?

Comment: It's part of the life cycle events you will get on your AppDelegate class (as with `-didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`) after requesting a push subscription `registerForRemoteNotificationsOfType:`. You'll get the token after you've registered for remote notifications, so you can either do this before you login, or after. Keep in mind that this is not a permanent token, and you need to update your server's token registry when it changes.

Comment: 1) You get the token by registering. You do the register whenever you see fit.  2) The token comes on the callback if the user permits. No need to store it on the phone or with apple.  Store it on your service.  The os records user permission, and will give you the token again on register with no ui, but you don't really need it on the phone.

Comment: Thanks Sveinung. The fact that the token isn't permanent is very important, as our subscriptions need to be maintained to the device even if the token changes. That means we have to store the UDID also. If the user does a Factory reset on the device, then they have essentially removed our app, which is fine.